# How helpful is rkhunter?

Tags: webserver, hardening, ports, rootkits

I have a software firewall implemented on my server, and I have closed all unnecessary ports. I have strong passwords, and I validate user input on my website.

With these things already in place, **do you recommend I use rkhunter** to help detect rootkits? Or would that be unnecessary?

Answer (score 8):

**Quick Answers**

The quickest answers are: "defense-in-depth", and "plan for failure"

You have protections in place, but what if they fail? What if an attacker finds a way in using a method that you did not anticipate? From these perspectives, then, yes, rkhunter is necessary.

But, then you start asking, "when do I stop adding more protection?"

**Right Answers** 
 
There is a calculation you have to perform about what the risks are and how probable they are, what the costs are if those risks are realized, and the costs of mitigating those risks. Every piece of protection you put in place needs to be maintained and updated, which is a cost. If those costs are lower than the costs of having an incident, then it is worth it. If not, then you are spending more than you are protecting. This quick calculation is how you determine, *"is it necessary?"*

**Other Options**

There might be other more important considerations, depending on your situation. Logging? Backups? Encryption? Ease of blowing away the server and rebuilding from known good? Web Application Firewalls? Secure web application design (apart from inputs)? Getting a good third-party review of your entire environment might highlight the *more* important components.

I hope these ideas help.

Comment: I commend you for recognizing that security is an economic good, with a value, and a price, and an opportunity cost. rkhunter appears to be linux (or maybe linux & BSD & unix) specific.  Without knowing what distro the asker uses, the price and opportunity cost are impossible to calculate.

Comment: @BruceEdiger Why would the distro have an impact on the calculation?

Comment: Suppose the distro is Arch, with a rolllig release and a preference for "cutting edge". It will be harder for someone to write a root kit, as Arch installation continually roll kernel versions and directory structures.

Comment: And yet Arch itself suggests rkhunter (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AIDE). The principle is the same for the OP regardless of distro, and I was not attempting to perform the calculation for him, but to guide him in his own considerations.

Comment: Is that a real suggestion, or a "motherhood and apple pie" suggestion, like early PCI DSS insistence on a "malware checker" on every computer, which was slightly ridiculous for say, Paymentech's Stratus front ends.

Comment: @BruceEdiger I'm confused, are you debating against the need for rkhunter, or against performing a risk calculation pertinent to the environment context?

Comment: Not debating the need for a risk calculation.  But I don't believe that rkhunter does all that much: the only realy root kit I ever got hit with still wouldn't be detected. I am arguing against making an absolute requirement for linux out of a "best practice" for windows installations.

Comment: Oh good, because I was not making an absolute requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should be using rkhunter (or similar) and also other security tools - how much time and effort depends on the value of the service, but in addition to a firewall I would recommend (as a basic setup):

- some method for identifying required security patches - an automated solution may seem like a lot more effort - but even for a low value website, you should be checking at least once a week.
- additional protection for ssh access - of course you have disabled root ssh access and restricted access to only a named group, but it's still a good idea to use port-knocking or fail2ban to cut down on the noise
- a file interity checker - if you ever do get hacked, this is vital to getting your system back online and secure
- a rootkit detector
- regular backups - and do test them to make sure you can get back to a working system